# memory leak problem concerning linux OS and htop command

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, linux-kernel, htop

I am testing my C code and detecting memory leak. This piece of code has two functions:

- one of which is to **initialize** a struct context and allocate momory.
- the other is to **finalize** this struct context and release memory

I make a loop over these 2 functions like below:

```
struct context = NULL;
while (1) {

    initialize(&context);
    sleep(30);
    finalize(&context);
    sleep(30);

}
```

And then, I use the `htop` to monitor the memory leak and get the results below:

```
VIRT RES   -> VIRT RES
745M 78588 -> 126M 24752
672M 79112 -> 281M 51072
671M 81224 -> 281M 55300
671M 81224 -> 281M 55300
671M 81252 -> 281M 55332
671M 96488 -> 281M 70560
671M 102M  -> 281M 79368
671M 102M  -> 281M 79376
671M 109M  -> 281M 85724
671M 111M  -> 281M 88152
```

- The table consists of **10** lines. every line is the change of memory in one loop.
- The left part is the memory state when I **initialized** the context, and the right part is the memory state when I **finalized and released** the context.
- I recorded **VIRT and RES** column number in every state.
- As shown above, `VIRT` the program occupied is a fixed number: `671M`(when initialized) and `281M`(when released). But the `RES` is gradually increasing by every loop.

My question is: **Is this called memory leak?**

Comment: "Is this called memory leak?" - A memory leak is a resource which is not no longer needed by a program but is not released. The tool `htop` doesn't detect such not released and not needed resources, so the tool doesn't give you a memory leak. As for increased memory consumption reported by `htop`, it could be caused by many factors. A memory leak is one of possible factors. So you are better to check for leaks by some **appropriate tool**.

Comment: How and when does the linux OS transfer `RES` memory into `VIRT`?   does `VIRT` value being constant as a sign of good memory management?